# multithread segment fault destructors

Tags: c++, pthreads, destructor, segment

i have a segment fault when it calls the function unit_thread_data，Actually it is caused by ~Data(). thread1 is all right, but thread2 cause the segment fault, the whole code is as fallows:(forgive the poor code style), error info is double free or corruption. Other info: gcc5.4.0, centos7. any help? thank you very much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
class Data
{
public:
    int* A_;
    Data()
    {
        cout<<"111\n";
        A_=NULL;
    }
    ~Data()
    {
        cout<<"222\n";
        if(A_) {
            delete A_;
        }
    }
};

struct thread_data_t
{
    Data* d;
};

void* _add(void* _pthread_data)
{
    thread_data_t* pthread_data = (thread_data_t*) _pthread_data;
    pthread_data->d->A_ = new int[2];
    pthread_data->d->A_[0] = 1;
    pthread_data->d->A_[1] = 2;
    std::cout<<pthread_data->d->A_[0]+pthread_data->d->A_[1]<<endl;
    return (void*)0;
}

void unit_thread_data(thread_data_t* pthread_data)
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        delete[] pthread_data[i].d->A_;
        delete pthread_data[i].d;
    }
    delete[] pthread_data;
}
int main()
{
    int num_threads = 2;
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    thread_data_t* pthread_data = new thread_data_t[num_threads];
    for(int i=0;i<num_threads; i++)
    {
        pthread_data[i].d = new Data();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, _add, (void*)(pthread_data+i));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    sleep(1);
    unit_thread_data(pthread_data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `delete[] pthread_data[i].d->A_;`, `A_` is deleted by destructor of `Data`.

Comment: Recommendation: If you are using C++11 or newer, use the standard [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) class instead of the platform specific C API `pthread`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need to test whether `A_` is null in the destructor. `delete A_;` can handle a null pointer.

Comment: @Pete Becker: thank you Pete, i have learnt it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete[] pthread_data[i].d->A_;
```

This deletes the `A_` member of your `Data` class, an `int *`.

Immediately afterwards, this happens:

```
delete pthread_data[i].d;
```

And this deletes the `Data` itself. `Data`'s destructor then does the following:

```
    if(A_) {
        delete A_;
    }
```

This then proceeds to attempt `delete` the same pointer. This should be `delete[]`d instead of `delete`d in the first place, but this is moot because this pointer is already `delete`d, and this tries to `delete` it a 2nd time.

This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: yes! I got it, thank you Sam :)

Answer (score 3):

It is because you first delete member `A_` here:

```
delete[] pthread_data[i].d->A_;
```

without assigning `nullptr` to `A_` afterwards, and then you call `delete A_;` in the destructor.

Apart from that, in your code it is not clear who should be the owner of the memory allocated under `A_` (functions `_add` and `unit_thread_data`, or a class itself), hence it is easy to do this kind of mistakes.

Quick fix (not recommended): just remove your destructor's body, and let your external functions `_add` and `unit_thread_data` manage the memory.

Better fix (recommended): think about who should be the owner of the allocated data (I would say `class Data`) and use `std::unique_ptr` if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign NULL after deleting A_.